# Problems linking to an object file created with cuda nvcc

Tags: linker, cuda, nvcc

I am trying to link to an object file generated by NVCC. Here a very simple "library":

```
//foo.cu:
void foo() {
}
```

And the file that uses the "library":

```
//main.cu:
extern void foo();

int main(){
foo();
}
```

Note, I circumvent the need for a include file in this simple setup by declaring the function directly in the file. Here the command I tried to build this:

```
nvcc -c foo.cu -arch=sm_20
nvcc main.cu foo.o -arch=sm_20
```

Why is this not working with NVCC? The second command produces tons of:

```
warning: null character(s) ignored
error: unrecognized token
```

I tried on a different machine with a different CUDA installation (4.0). Same strange compiler/linker output.

I also tried using `extern "C"` instead of the C++ name mangling. Same behavior. Besides, C name mangling is not an option in the real application.

Comment: Why are you calling nvcc with both an object file and a source file? That sort of guarantees weirdness, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Unbelievable, reversing the order of arguments in the second call fixes this.

```
nvcc foo.o main.cu -arch=sm_20
```

(Sigh)